# C# Visual studio 2010 publish files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Is there an option to pack the files to distribute into a single executable instead of three executable, a folder, and other misc files?

Comment: @ErikPhilips, if you have ever used C# visual studio 2010 express. Then you would know what I was referring to. It is the only option provided for building an application so instead of being a smart ass that doesn't understand my situation.

Comment: Do you mean files to install visual studio or to publish a project created within visual studio?

Comment: Something like this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146626/Extending-Visual-Studio-Setup-Project

Answer (score 1):

ILMerge utility can be used for merge different assemblies into single one. Available to download at http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17630

Resources files can be embedded in assemblies as well.

Comment: I need to use the publishing feature that visual studio provides. Also merging only the executable would not allow the installation file to run since it will give off a missing files error.

Comment: I doubt that you would get out of box 'as it is' you need. For missing files, I once embedded them into assemblies so they can be retrieved at runtime.